# How can I put a demon altar in my house?

Tags: terraria

I'd like to make a compact crafting station, so I think I'd like to place a demon altar, like in the Terraria [Crafting 101 Guide](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Crafting_101).

[image: Crafting Station]

But, how can I actually obtain one? The wiki says that hitting them before destroying the Wall of Flesh only results in the player taking damage.

How can I pick up or obtain an altar?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Demon Altars cannot be moved or placed without maphacking. The only option is to destroy them (with the Pwnhammer or Hamdrax).

In the screenshot you provided, it looks like that they took their compact crafting station to the altar, rather than the other way around (like you were hoping to do so).